# Shift row values to column values Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a tab separated file like

```
text_id text    task_1  task_2  task_3
hasoc_en_1  in the know as nation's pride is involved    lorem  NOT NONE    NONE
hasoc_en_2  admitted to treason . #TrumpIsATraitor  #McCainsAHero #JohnMcCainDay    HOF HATE    TIN
```

I can read it into a dataframe like

```
df=pd.read_csv(r"c:\Users\asd\Desktop\dd\english_dataset\english_dataset.tsv", sep='\t', header=0)
```

I want to have all unique values in task_1, task_2 and task_3 as column headers and 1 or 0 as row value, for example:

```
text_id text    NOT HOF NONE HATE TIN
hasoc_en_1  in the know as nation's pride is involved    lorem  1 0 1 0 0
hasoc_en_2  admitted to treason . #TrumpIsATraitor  #McCainsAHero #JohnMcCainDay    0 1 0 1 0
```

is there any built in function or an easy way to do it? or do i have to loop through one dataframe and insert values in other one. suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas.get_dummies() https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html for each separate task column and then take max to convert them into form you request/